# Add curvature to the edge of my UV Sphere that has a hole through it

Tags: uv

Could someone tell me how i could add a curvature to the edge of this sphere hole?
[image: Sphere]

Comment: Hello, could you please elaborate a bit? it's hard to understand the topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We, people from forensic department ... we already know :)

But yes ... please  use more illustrative screenshot like - switch to edit mode to see wire (topology) of your mesh with probably more distance so we can get more context.*

[image]

If I'm right ... just select top edge loop <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
And Bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> it (with Middle mouse add more loops.

[image]

Or use **Bevel** modifier as non destructive ... just create a **Vertex group** from top vertices.

[image]

[image]